# Visual Studio 2012 LNK1168 every time I re-run the project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

Let's say I have a project X. Pressing CTRL-F5 on it runs without debugging, everything works fine, however when I close the project (Either by input, either by ESC or either by using the cross) it remains in the processes and I cannot run it the second time, because I get a LNK1168 error, and the only solution is shutting down the process manually every time I try to run the project. I'm using the latest version of Avast, I tried adding an exception to my projects folder, and I'm using windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012 express.

Comment: Check to see if you've spun off a thread which isn't being killed.

Comment: My program is not multi-threaded

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading `handle.exe` and checking to see what is stopping your program from ending.

[Handle download](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).

Just open an administrator command prompt and run

```
handle.exe processname
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure you don't have the program running in the background. Find the console window that is open and close it.

If that does not work try enabling the "Application Experience" service.